# Доступ к вложенному словарю по списку ключей

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, dict

Есть словарь и список ключей, по которому нужно получить значение из первого

```
dictonary = {
'level1A': {'level2A': 'valueAA', 'level2B': 'valueAB'},
'level1B': {'level2A': 'valueBA', 'level2B': 'valueBB'}
}

keylist = ['level1B', 'level2A']
```

Вопрос: как из 'value2A' сделать любое другое значение? По возможности используйте `dict[key] = 'value'`, чтобы я мог настроить добавление элемента `dict[addedkey] = 'addedvalue'` и его удаление `del dict[delkey]` или подскажите другие варианты это сделать (это мне тоже надо, забыл сразу указать, а создавать новый вопрос как по мне не очень логично).

```
dictonary['level1B']['level2B'] = 'newvalue' #это работает, но нужно знать уровень вложенности
dictonary[keylist] = 'newvalue' #нужен рабочий аналог этого действия, т. к. "TypeError: unhashable type: list"
```

Вложенность dictonary и длина keylist могут быть любыми. 
Я пробовал получить каждую вложенность в список, изменить самую глубокую и "собрать" словарь обратно, но либо я накосячил в коде, либо метод не работает. Вот метод для получения вложенности (он рабочий):

```
def getlevel(dictonary, keylist): 
    res = dictonary
    for d in keylist:
        res = res[d]
    return dictonary
```

P.S. Имена переменных любые, главное, чтобы я понял, где словарь, а где список ключей. 
EDIT: На самом деле, задача состоит в возможности не только изменения, но и добавления и удаления ключей и значений.
EDIT2:В списке ключей каждый следующий ключ для следующего "уровня" словаря. Первый элемент - ключ для первого "уровня", второй для второго и т.д. И каждый новый "уровень" - значение ключа на предыдущем "уровне". И значение последнего ключа в списке ключей не обязано быть определенным типом данных; это тоже может быть словарь, но там я разберусь. "Уровень" - словарь-значение у текущего ключа в списке ключей. Первый "уровень" - "корневой словарь", у меня в нём определены level1A и level1B

Comment: что такое `'value2A'` и что такое `foo` в вашем описании?

Comment: @SergFSM не foo, а dictonary, это я ошибся, уже исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Спускаемся по вложеным словарям, кроме последнего. В последний словарь по последнему ключу записываем значение:

```
def set_value(d, keys, value):
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        d = d[k]
    d[keys[-1]] = value
```

Можно создавать словари на лету:

```
def set_value(d, keys, value):
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        d = d.setdefault(k, {})
    d[keys[-1]] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

@proger786, Если `keylist` организован как список, содержащий список 2ух ключей для доступа то  так:

```
dictonary = {
'level1A': {'level2A': 'valueAA', 'level2B': 'valueAB'},
'level1B': {'level2A': 'valueBA', 'level2B': 'valueBB'}}

keylist = [['level1B', 'level2A']]


def get_data(tuplekey, dict_data):
    key1, key2 = tuplekey
    return dict_data[key1][key2]

for element_lst in keylist:
    print(get_data(tuplekey=element_lst, dict_data=dictonary))
```

Если не так, но напишите поподробнее про `keylist`

Answer (score 0):

Этот код ищет во всех вложенных словарях.

`getval()` возвращает первое найденное совпадение (у вас в словарях ключи дублируются):

```
dictionary = {
'level1A': {'level2A': 'valueAA', 'level2B': {'level3': 'value3'}},
'level1B': {'level2A': 'valueBA', 'level2B': 'valueBB'}}

keylist = ['level1B', 'level2A', 'level2B', 'level3', 'level4']

def getval(k, d=dictionary):
    res = None
    if k in d: return d[k]
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(d[i], dict): res = getval(k, d[i])
        if res: return res
    
for i in keylist:
    print(f'{i} = {getval(i)}')
```

результат:

```
level1B = {'level2A': 'valueBA', 'level2B': 'valueBB'}
level2A = valueAA
level2B = {'level3': 'value3'}
level3 = value3
level4 = None
```

Comment: В keylist каждый следующий ключ для следующего "уровня" словаря. Первый элемент - ключ для первого "уровня", второй для второго и т.д. И каждый новый "уровень" - значение ключа на предыдущем "уровне". И значение последнего ключа в keylist не обязано быть определённым типом данных; это тоже может быть словарь, но там я разберусь. "Уровень" - словарь-значение у текущего ключа в keylist. Первый "уровень" - "корневой словарь", у меня в нём определены level1A и level1B.

Comment: @akmast16 приведите в своем вопросе пример того, что вы хотите получить в результате

Answer (score 0):

До конца не понял что вы хотите в итоге получить. Попробуйте это:

```
dictionary = {
'level1A': {'level2A': 'valueAA', 'level2B': 'valueAB'},
'level1B': {'level2A': {'level3': 'value3'}, 'level2B': 'valueBB'}
}

keylist = ['level1B', 'level2A', 'level3']

def func(k,d=dictionary):
    if type(d)==dict: v = d.get(k.pop(0),-1)
    else: return -1
    return v if not k else func(k,v)
```

результат (-1 если значение не найдено):

```
func(keylist)  # 'value3'
```

Comment: Этот код работает как мой getlevel(). Мне нужно изменение, а не чтение.